# Is there a notation named sensor in nltk?

Tags: nltk

I am learning Stanford CS224N: natural language processing with Deep Learning.

Chris said

> "very fine-grain differences between sensors that are a human being
>   can barely understand the difference between them and relate to"

in [Lecture 1](https://youtu.be/8rXD5-xhemo?t=1506) while he is illustrating the piece of NLTK code.

Is there a notation named sensor in nltk? if yes, what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the automatic captioning of Youtube is wrong and that the lecturer pronounced the word [synset](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/synset).

And yes, there is a notation for synsets in [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/), in fact the notation is coming from [Wordnet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/).

You can get a synset with:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
dog = wn.synset('dog.n.01')
```

where *dog* is the morphological stem of one of the lemma, *n* is the part of speech (noun in this case), and *01* is an index.

According to the [NLTK documentation](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.corpus.reader.html#nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet.Synset):

> **Synset(wordnet_corpus_reader)**
>
> Create a Synset from a *lemma.pos.number* string where: *lemma* is the word’s morphological stem *pos* is one of the module attributes ADJ, ADJ_SAT, ADV, NOUN or VERB *number* is the sense number, counting from 0.